# How to generate two seperate serenity reports for two seperate cucumber tests using the same runner class?

Tags: selenium, gradle, junit, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I have two cucumber feature files.
1) Feature 1
2) Feature 2

I have one CucumberWithSerenity runner class.

When I run both feature files together, using the same runner class the report generation is failing with the below error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':runTests'.

  > Multiple build operations failed.
  >     Could not write XML test results

It's a gradle based project, and the task fails.

My observations:

As the serenity is saving the results/screenshots for both the feature files in the same below directory : /target/site/ it's failing to generate two seperate reports at run time. Please can I get some help on how to generate two seperate reports for both feature files using the same runner class.

Comment: I'm not sure that's Serenity-related (Serenity doesn't produce XML reports, only JSON ones). What versions are you using?

Comment: No John, it's not that the issue, as when I run two features/scenarios the results for both the scenarios are getting stored in /target/site/serenity folder, and the report generation is failing, maybe because I am using same serenity-junit runner class to run both of my tests and Junit is trying to generate an XML before generating the actual HTML reports. What I want to achieve is, when I run two gradle tasks together for two different features/scenarios using -tags, I want seperate HTML reports to be generated. Please can you help me how can I achieve this?

Comment: I use the below:
dependencies {
    'serenity-core', version: '2.0.48'
    'serenity-junit', version: '2.0.48'
    'junit', version: '4.12'
    'serenity-cucumber', version: '1.9.45'
}

Comment: Have marked *** for the names, this is my runner class


import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/resources/features/***/","src/test/resources/features/***/"},
 /*plugin = {
 "rerun:rerun.txt"},glue={"com/***/***/features/steps/","com/***/**/features/steps/"})*/
plugin = {},glue={"com/***/***/features/steps/","com/***/***/features/steps/"})
public class AcceptanceTests {

}

Comment: Here are my commands to run the test,
Terminal 1 : gradle clean runTests -Denv=“test”  -Dcucumber.options="--tags @test123” --info

Terminal 2 : gradle clean runTests -Denv=“test”  -Dcucumber.options="--tags @test345” --info

When executed together, want the tests to generate two seperate HTML reports. It will be of great help if you could help me achieve this?